# Toast message from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, toast

I have a broadcast receiver and I am trying to show a toast message from it, is this possible ?
This code doesn't show the toast but it print the log message in the logcat. Is there some idiotic thing I am doing or what is my problem ?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("log", "this is shown");
    Toast.makeText(context, "this is not shown"     , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Comment: As lukuluku suggests, creating a `Toast` from a `BroadcastReceiver` isn't necessarily a good thing to do. It's possible your `BroadcastReceiver` may be 'alive' when some other `Activity` is in use. In this case, the `Toast` will make no sense to the user of the device.

Comment: @Squonk sure, it's not a good thing in general, but useful in [cases like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23135951/504611).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Call the `show()` method for the `Toast`.

Comment: I had to come all the way here to find out that I'm an idiot too. Thanks man. +1.

Comment: And another one here :P

Comment: and one more is added

Comment: And one more added after a long period of time...

Answer (score 12):

you forgot to call `show()` on the `Toast`..
although i would not recommend creating toasts from BroadcastReceivers.. you might consider using Notifications

Comment: I know i'm a little late, but why create toasts from BroadcastReceivers isn't a good idea?

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos Because the user might be confused and won't know which app has created the toast message. Imagine dozens of apps spawning toast messages - this would be more confusion than helpful.

Comment: Understood! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 6):

**Use this**

`Toast.makeText(context, "this is not shown",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`