# How can I get message Android and show it in my activity?

Tags: android, message

I had receiver message through `broadcast Receiver` and show it through `Toast`. But I want show it in my `Activity`. Everyone help me? Thanks you!!

Comment: this may help you i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900976/toast-message-from-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just launch another activity once you receive the message, Braodcast receiver is not an activity, so you cant display stuff from there directly.

Comment: and  have another activity registerReceiver() ??? i don't know receiver message in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a TextView in your activity, then use `TextView.setText()` method to show the message you received.