# Why Toast.maketoast is not working in the BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-broadcastreceiver, android-toast

I am getting the Error message while i am trying to call the Toast.makeText function inside the onReceive function of the BroadcastReceiver type class.
This is not a duplicate of [another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900976/toast-message-from-broadcast-receiver) because i am calling the show() method and this is compile time issue
Error is : cannot resolve method makeText.

The same function working fine if i am calling it inside any other Activity Type Class.

Here is my code that i am trying to run .

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CallStateReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toast message from Broadcast Receiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900976/toast-message-from-broadcast-receiver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess its having trouble with the `context`. Change it to:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass **Context** from BroadcastReceiver class to Toast.change your toast onReceive method like below

```
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  Toast.makeText(context,"test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
Toast.makeText(this,"test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to this

```
Toast.makeText(context,"test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and try