# How to track sync service in Android to show progessBar in main activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-syncadapter

I am currently making an App, which needs to download some photos from server side. I have developed one Sync Service (based on SyncAdapter concept from Google) and I would like to show a progressBar, while the photos are downloading. The problem is my syncAdapter class is a non-activity and my main class is an activity class. When I call the sync request in the activity class, the progressBar comes up, but I cannot realize when the sync service is completed. Anyone has an idea , how can I track the sync Service  to realize when it is completed?

Thanks

Comment: i think this question is answer for your solution check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268536/how-does-one-listen-for-progress-from-android-syncadapter)

Comment: The section on results and progress in this article may be of use http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter

Comment: This question has been answered in this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268536/how-does-one-listen-for-progress-from-android-syncadapter/23135951?noredirect=1